# How do I get a list of discussions for a row using the Smartsheet REST API?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I need to access all discussions for a Smartsheet row via the [REST API](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation).

Is there a way to do this?  Calling https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/row/{ID}/discussions, which isn't documented, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint was a good guess, and its definitely on our radar for implementation in the future. For now, though, you'll need to use the GET /row/{id} using the include query string parameter:

```
GET /row/{id}?include=discussions
```

This will give you the entire row object, with an attribute "discussions" that has an array of discussion objects. See [this](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.6m37wiv17it0) for details.